Voting in India
In my region (country India) election will happen in few days. Today few members from X party came to our house and asked for voter id of all family member. My dumb parents handed them all the voter id we had. They took photo of each voter id. In return they gave Y amount of money to us. Value of Y is depended on number of valid voter id (potential voter) we showed them. Party X not only have photo of voter id of my family but also they have thousands of photo from all my neighbour buildings. Now my question is
(1) Since X party have photo of voter id, can they secretly (without consent of that voter) give vote to themselves?
(2) Is it legal to give money to people for potential vote? Isn’t this just bribery? What would be the consequence if this kind of thing happened in USA?
I am sorry if these are low quality question. I recently got my voter id. This will be my first time going to vote someone. So I don’t know most of the stuff related to voting.
